# Passing component as a function argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a function that take a component as argument, and return another, enhanced component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Layout, DarkBar } from 'SharedComponents/Layouts';


const myCreationFunction = ({
  component,
}) => {
  const Route = (props) => {
    // Some code here 
    return (
      <Layout>
          <div><Link to={props.path}>LinkTitleHere</Link></div>
          {React.createElement(component, {
            ...props,
            ...someOtherPropsHere,
          })}
      </Layout>
    );
  }; // The error points here

  const mapStateToProps = () => ({});
  const enhance = compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps, someActionsHere),
  )(Route);

  return enhance;
};
```

I invoke that function in this way:

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
import myCreationFunction from './HOC/myCreationFunction';

const Route = myCreationFunction({
  component: MyComponent,
});
```

When I run it in the development mode, it runs smoothly. But when trying to build the app using `npm run build` and going through webpack, I get:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (35:47)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
| 
> var createListRoute = function myCreationFunction((_temp = _ref, _ref2 = <_Layouts.DarkBar>
|           <_Breadcrumbs2.default />
|           <_Layouts.RoundAddButton path={addPath} color="white" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit #1**

It seems that the `<Link>` is causing the problem. Removing it fixed the problem. Also, when trying to replace it with `a` tag, I get the same issue. Weird.

**Edit #2**

I have not resolved this issue because of lack of time. I was trying for 1 hour without any progress and decided to go with `button` tag and `onClick` method that uses `history` to push the new url.

It was and is really weird to me, that a `Link` or `<a>` tag can break something during the build process itself. I will definitely jump deeper into it in some free time.

Comment: Point us to this file and to this line

Comment: What line is that error pointing to?!

Comment: I updated the error trace. Sorry for inconvenience. The line 35 is actually the end of `Route` - the `}` sign.

Comment: Its look like some packages installed in DevMode only and not available for prod node. Its related to transpilers

Comment: Are you using a custom webpack config? If so, could you edit it into your question? The babel config as well. It seems like that's where the problem is

Comment: I have no idea why, but I had `Link` from react-router in the code. Commenting this and it works. I can't also place a `<a href>` inside the code as it also brakes that thing :/

Comment: Are you perhaps using some starter project with different webpack configs for development and production builds?

Comment: I am, but this problem started happening yesterday, when I wrapped this `Route` component in a function like this. It does not happen without it